# Regular expression over the following language

Tags: regular-language

Alphabet E = {a, b, c}

**Question and answer:** http://d.pr/i/3N41

[image]

I understand we must have two a's on the outside but why do we have `[]` and `*` - what do these do for this particular expression? In addition to this I'm not quite sure what this means http://d.pr/i/uff7 - `{ w | |W|}` is it just a variable to put the language into?

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Paul instead link image you can post question with image

Comment: Thanks, didn't have the rep to do it last time :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer the second half of your questions first, that expression can be described as follows:

The language *L<sub>a</sub>* is comprised of the set of words *w*, where the length of *w* is a multiple of 3 and *w* starts with **aa**.

The vertical bar introduces the conditions that *w* must meet to be included in the set.

The bars on either side of the second *w* indicate length.

Then looking at the answer, you have *aa*, because that's what the word must start with, followed by one other letter (*a*, *b* or *c*), giving you a 3 letter word that's a match.

After that, any other words would need to have an additional 3 letters, each of which can be *a*, *b* or *c*. So the asterisk (*) indicates that this can occur 0 or more times, and the brackets [] just denote which part of the expression the asterisk applies to.

Answer (score 2):

The way I would write this in Bash is aa[abc]([abc][abc][abc])* which means that
the token should start with a "aa" followed by `'a'` or `'b'` or `'c'` hence `( aa[abc] )`

`[abc]` is equivalent to `(a + b + c)` in formal representation means `'a'` or `'b'` or `'c`'

`x*` means `'x'` any number of times, *including zero*

so `([abc][abc][abc])*` means `(('a' or 'b'  or 'c')` three times) occurring any number of times.

the formal way to express that is `[(a+b+c)(a+b+c)(a+b+c)]*`

the square brackets are like normal parentheses (unlike Bash or Javascript regular expressions for example) but we usually use them when the enclosed portion already has parentheses inside to enhance readability. The asterisk applies to the hole block enclosed in square brackets preceding it.

Answer (score 0):

In this case `[...]` is grouping three-letter series, and `*` means 0 or more occurrences.

You have "aa" and then you must have one letter, so that there is (a+b+c) and the rest is optional.

Comment: How come we need to group three-letter series though? And 0 or more for what exactly?

Comment: 0 or more repeats of three letters, e.g. "aaa", "abc" and so on

Comment: So it repeats so that it's a multiple of 3? And what was the reason for grouping with []? From what I can tell, if i was to choose from the answer I could get: aababc (chosen randomly) but what difference does the * make? Still a little confused.

Comment: So that it can be aababc as well as aababcacbbca

Comment: I see, thanks! Last question, I've not come across the [] before, what's the *most* specific reason for using them?

Comment: To group elements, without this if you would have (a+b+c)(a+b+c)(a+b+c)* the "*" would affect only last "(a+b+c")"